# gmtime change two pointers at the same time

Tags: c++, datetime

I have this code:

```
time_t tt = time(NULL);
tm* currentTime = gmtime(&tt);
tm* storedTime = gmtime(&m_time);
```

Where m_time is a time_t member data set at construction time.
When I set storedTime with this data member, current time acquires the same value, as if both tm pointers points to the same variable. Is this the expected behavior?  How could I have separated tm structs to compare times?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From documentation about `gmtime`:

> This structure is **statically allocated** and shared by the functions gmtime and localtime. **Each time either one of these functions is called the contents of this structure is overwritten**.

Use this code to create a copy:

```
time_t tt = time(NULL);

tm currentTime = *gmtime(&tt);
tm storedTime = *gmtime(&m_time);
```

(pointer deference here is equivalent to `memcpy(&currentTime, gmtime(&tt), sizeof(tm))`)

Comment: Or `tm currentTime = *gmtime(&tt);`. It seems cleaner to me for some reason :)

Comment: @Fiktik you're so right! memcpy should be just added as comment

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that they are returning the address of a local static variable.  E.g.

```
struct tm *gmtime(struct time_t *tt)
{
    static struct tm local_tm;
    /* do work */
    return &local_tm;
}
```

Looking at man pages across the internet (I google "man gmtime"), it is a common theme that this is not a re-entrant function, and may even share a return value with other functions:

> POSIX.1-2001 says: "The asctime(), ctime(), gmtime(), and localtime()
>   functions shall return values in one of two static objects: a
>   broken-down time structure and an array of type char. Execution of any
>   of the functions may overwrite the information returned in either of
>   these objects by any of the other functions."